# Good WSYIWIG for Code Snippets

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, code-snippets

I am looking for a WYSIWIG that supports code snippets. I've tried using TinyMCE and CKEditor but there does not seem to be an addo n for handling snippets of code, specifically those in HTML or PHP.

If there is a good one, can anyone give any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [wmd](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/)

The very own used in Stackoverflow :)

But this does not actually satisfy one of your conditions, which is WYSIWYG part...

This is a WYSIWYM editor :)

WYSIWYM stands for What You See Is What You Mean